# Adobe Flash Save multiple pivot points on 2 layers

Tags: adobe-flash

I'd like to animate a stick figure. I made a layer for every body part. Now I need to predefine the rotation point somewhere. I used symbols to save the pivot position.

The problem is that I can only create one symbol per layer. If I select two elements like the top and bottom leg and creating a symbol, I cannot select the single symbol anymore. Both parts always connected then.

How can I save multiple pivot points?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can save a pivot point in Flash, aside from moving the symbol in the <kbd>Edit Symbol</kbd> view and aligning the shape to the center point.

You can however, change the rotation pivot point to where ever you want when rotating with the transform tool `Q`.

[image]

So to solve your problem you would simply keyframe your shape with the pivot point in the first position. Then when the pivot needs to move, you can adjust and move it to the next.

In the sample below, I have the pivot point for the top and bottom shapes at their respective tops.

[image: example]

***Just a note:*** The pivot point will be stored where ever you put it in that keyframe until you move it and re-key or enter another keyframe.