# Adobe Flash get angle of layer (rotation value)

Tags: adobe-flash

How can I get the angle of a rotated layer. Or is it possible to see the angle while rotating? If so, where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Transform window will show the rotation of the selected object.

<kbd>Window > Transform</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

[image]

Comment: But this rotation do not move around the pivot point for some reason

Comment: @Abc You have to set the pivot point first by moving it where you want it like in this answer: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/26248/12189